# Как использовать экземпляр Gson внутри Serializer/Deserializer класса?

Tags: java, gson

Пример:

```
public class HistoryRecordDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<HistoryRecord> {

    private LocalDateTimeConverter dateTimeConverter = new LocalDateTimeConverter();

    @Override
    public HistoryRecord deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(UUUID.fromString(json.get("user").get("id").getAsString()));
        OtherData data = new OtherData();
        data.setData(json.get("otherData").getAsLong());
        return UserAndData(user, otherData);
    }
```

Я вручную десериализую объекты User и OtherData. Как можно сделать лучше? Есть идея использовать экземпляр Gson, передав его в конструкторе, или же создавать новый в `HistoryRecordDeserializer`. Есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему использованием `JsonDeserializationContext`, который передается в катчестве аргумента метода `JsonDeserializer.deserialize(...)`.

Например:

```
@Override
public HistoryRecord deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject object = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonObject extras = object.get("extraData").getAsJsonObject();

    HistoryRecord hr = context.deserialize(object.get("data"), HistoryRecord.class);
    hr.appendExtraData(extras, HistoryRecordExtraData.class);
    ...
    }
```

По факту контекст умеет десериализовать все то же, что и экземпляр `Gson`-а. Передавать инстанс `Gson` надобность отпадает.

Еще пример:

```
UUID id = context.deserialize(object.get("id"), UUID.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете какой либо DI-framework, то его можно заинжектить:
`@Inject`(JavaEE или Guice) или `@Autowired`(Spring).

Соответственно, в одном месте можно будет создать единственный экземпляр `Gson`, а также контролировать все его настройки.